# jQuery .addClass(Dynamic) use outside .each() function

Tags: jquery, each, addclass

I got this working code:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('cycle-slideshow-randomid--' + i);
});
```

Now I want to use this `randomid` in the code below (this code is not part of the previous .each()) but how?

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-paused', function(event, optionHash) {/**/});
```

I tried this:

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow-randomid--' + i ).on( 'cycle-paused', function(event, optionHash) {/**/});
```

But it did not work? Thanks for helping!

I also tried making it into a var inside the .each() but it did not recognize it. So I probably did that wrong.

I hope to get it into a variable so that I can then use a IF (.cycle-slideshow-randomid--1) aswell as the normal variable in the .on().

Comment: You do realize `i` is not a number, right? `each` has a defined set of params

Comment: That is rather strange as that function returns `cycle-slideshow-randomid--0`, `cycle-slideshow-randomid--1` etc. At least that is what the inspector says ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but, you can add your event handler on all corresponding element like that :

```
$("[class*='cycle-slideshow-randomid--']").on('cycle-paused', function(event, optionHash) {/**/});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Love it. But is it missing a `]` in your code or am I not seeing it ;-) I am getting the error: Error in event handler unknown. Or should I at the `]` all the way at the end?

Comment: You can check this exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/s4votgm1/ the selector should be : `$("[class*='cycle-slideshow-randomid--']")` (answer edited)

Comment: Oh I did not expect to get a Fiddle. Absolute superb it makes it so much easier to understand. I am going to try your code as soon as I am back at the office. Thank you so much for spending the time to teach me a few tricks.

Comment: Just tried it and it ain't working like I want. As I have 3 slideshows (0,1,2) when I hover over slideshow 1 it pauses that one and 0+2. So the prob. still exists but thank you anyway for all the trouble and looking forward to another reply.

Comment: If you provide a full js fiddle example to show your problem I can help you.

Comment: I tried creating a Fiddle but it won't work the same way as it is currently working inside a Joomla Module. On the website it works great (the entire code) but in the fiddle it won't work at all. Are you by any change familiar with Gitter? And are you willing to talk with me in private chat. I can send you files and access codes to the live website. I can't post those in here (not allowed) otherwise I would have done so already ;-)

Once again thank you very much for all the help already provided and offering even more. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Quentin Roger has saved me days of figuring this out by helping me in every single way it is amazing and his answer is correct even when I did not understood it directly. Once again thank you so much for helping out.